# using a text file with c++

Tags: c++

I have a text file containing 200 numbers. I want to calculate the average value of those numbers (because it takes way too long to do it by hand). I have no idea how to accomplish this, because I have never done such a thing. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I tried searching google but couldnt find something usefull.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: 1. What have you at least *tried*, and 2. Define *"numbers"*. Are they floating point? integers? Is the file comma-separated? whitespace-separated?

Comment: It sounds like you need to have such a tool by now and don't want to learn how to program. This implies you don't want to *try* to accomplish it by yourself. This isn't a case for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why C++? I'd open text file, CTRL+A to select all, CTRL+C to copy to clipboard, open spreadsheet, CTRL+V to paste, and then calc mean there.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You're so right. Know your tools. Know when to use which tool. :)

Comment: @David Heffernan I know how to do it with excell, but scince I am busy learning c++ I also want to do it with c++

Comment: When you wrote "because it takes way too long to do it by hand", we all interpreted that you just wanted to do this for one file right now. So if it's a teach yourself programming exercise, say so. And then tell us what you tried. Please tell us that you tried something before asking us.

Comment: A few things you might want to look up: [std::ifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream), [std::istream_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator), [std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

Comment: "I tried searching google but couldnt find something useful". Try harder. Search for "C++ read file". There are millions of examples of reading from files. I simply cannot believe that you have tried. If you can't find an example of how to read from a file you should give up programming.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: holy words, but i'm afraid they're completely lost on someone who is not even ready to invest an effort in solving his own problem. he is not likely going to take the effort to read those advices either. sadly, i think those pages are written more for *us* than for *them*. but again, holy words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple C++ program would implement the following steps:

1. Open the file as a text file (best use a command line argument as its file name, don't hardcode it)

   - Use a stream rather than a plain old C file handle; there are a lot of different possibilities to read files
2. Read it line by line and parse the line as a `double` value
3. Either store the values and calculate the average after reading all numbers or calculate the average on the fly while reading

   - Storing the values should happen in a dynamic datastructure like `std::vector`, read about it
   - Calculating on the fly would mean to sum up all values and increment a counter; divide the sum by the counter at the end
   - Take it as an exercise to implement both possibilities; to calculate the average of a `std::vector` there are again a lot of possibilities; try to find 3 different solutions to learn good C++ style. (google for *STL algorithms*)
4. Then print the result to the standard output with `cout`

Have a look at these steps and ask concrete questions if you encounter problems.

---

However, you don't need a C++ program to do this. A spreadsheet program is the perfect tool for this.

If you don't like GUI programs for such tasks, SQLite is a perfect tool, too. Open the SQLite shell and type (assuming `data.txt` is your file with a decimal number on each line):

```
create table tmp (value double);
.import data.txt tmp
select avg(value) from tmp;
```

Comment: I know I dont need c++, but I want to learn how to use data from a text file using c++. this is just an example

Comment: @Badshah I read your comment on your question too late, see my update; I added a brief overview of the program. Please ask more concrete questions on a single step if you encounter problems; Stack Overflow should not be used for writing whole programs by other users.